# ITU-R 2k filter implementation

Tags: c++, filtering

I have an array coming from a digitizer. I do an fft on it and then I calculate the frequency bins and apply a 20kHz low pass filter. The next step would be to apply an ITU-R 2k filter on this array and the filter behaves like the curve in the picture. I know I am supposed to do a multiplication one by one of the samples but I am not sure how to start with it. I know the 0 dB point is at 2 kHz and the maximum of 6 dB is located at 7 kHz. The implementation has to done in C++.
[itu-r 468 filter behavior](http://www.lindos.co.uk/FlexiData/Articles/files/image1/10/lindos3.png)

Comment: So what is your question, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

An LTI filter like this is a straightforward multiplication in the frequency domain. Put the filter coefficients in an array of the same length, multiply the two: `std::transform(std::begin(fftbins), std::end(fftbins), std::begin(filtercoeff), std::multiplies<std::complex<double>>());` and perform the IFFT.

Comment: I know but my problem is generating the coefficients of this filter

Comment: That's a problem for DSP.StackExchange.com, not a C++ problem.